# Check for relationships when listing resources

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

Having these 3 tables:

### users

- user_id
- first_name
- last_name
- etc.

### posts

- post_id
- title
- body
- etc.

### posts_users

- post_id
- user_id

The `post - user` relation means that a user is following a post.

The simplest way of listing posts would be:

```
$posts= Posts::all();

foreach ($posts as $post)
{
    var_dump($post->title);
}
```

But when listing posts I would love to also query if the current user (say user_id = 5) is following each post.

So for each post I would have `post_id`, `title`, ..., `is_following [0 or 1]`.

I can do this using simple SQL, but can this be done the Eloquent way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try eager loading the users and then for each post, loop through the users that are following that post looking for the user id.

```
$posts = Post::with('users')->get();

foreach($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->title;
    foreach($post->users as $user) {
        if($user->id == $user_id) {
            echo 'User with id of '.$user_id.' is following this post.';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the `Post` / `User` relationship defined on the `User` Model using `hasMany('Post')`, you can check if the current `Post` is in the user's followed posts using [`contains()`](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections):

```
$followed_posts = $current_user->posts();

if ($followed_posts->contains($current_post->id))
{
    // This Post is being followed by the User
    // .... Do something .... :)
}
```